# CQL create statements very slow

Tags: java, cassandra, datastax

I've created a project to automatically configure a keyspace and its associated column families on a C* cluster.  When I developed this on my box and our team dev environment, the cql statements executed very quickly, but when I run it (from my box) pointing to our test environment, each create statement takes ≈10 seconds to run.  Ping time to the test cluster is < 1ms.  As far as I can tell, the clusters are very similar, does anyone know any cluster settings that may need to be tuned?

Comment: Please take a trace and add it to the question (if it's not immediately obvious what the problem is from the trace).  To take a trace, see these instructions`http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/tracing-in-cassandra-1-2 .

Comment: How are you implementing this script? Are you running cqlsh in the local machine and then pointing it to the remote machine or are you running the procedure via a remote shell like ssh?